# Converting String from arraylist to another String

Tags: java, arraylist

Say I have the following Arraylist:

```
1. [123] [456] [789]
2. [134] [105] [455]
```

And have to follow the rules:

```
[123] [456] = cat
[789] = dog
[134] = mouse
[105] [455] = snake
```

And from Arraylist 1, I want to form the new following Array list:

1. cat dog
2. mouse snake

Is there anyway to do that. I currently haven't found anything for String to String conversion.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Which types are your first arrayLists with bracket value ? Integer? or String with integer?

Comment: They are String. Right now the only solution I can think of is to do if statement, as in if .getArray == [123] [456], then array[0] = cat or something along those line, but it can get repetitive if you have up to 20 rules to follow. I thought about doing a arraylist with all the conversion rule, but I'm not sure it's doable.

Comment: Then use hashmap instead of using arrayList if your mapping to values are unique and distinct

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this. This is only one of many possible ways; there maybe even better ways than this. You may consider this just an indicator of how to do this. The interesting class is the `Rules` class. This has the conversion rules implemented as `java.util.Pattern` instances and the `apply()` method in it does the conversion.

If you have input array of some other type than `String`, you may follow the general idea but a `Pattern` based implementation may not always work.

```
public class ListOfStringsToAnother{

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        List<String> inputStrings = getInputArray();

        List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
        for( String input : inputStrings ) {
            output.add( Rules.INSTANCE.apply( input ) );
        }

        output.forEach( System.out::println );
    }

    private static List<String> getInputArray(){
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList( "[123] [456] [789]", "[134] [105] [455]" );
        return list;
    }

    private static final class Rules{
        static Map<String, Pattern> patterns = new HashMap<>();
        static Rules INSTANCE = new Rules();

        private Rules() {
            patterns.put( "cat", Pattern.compile( "\\[123\\] \\[456\\]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE ) );
            patterns.put( "dog", Pattern.compile( "\\[789\\]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE ) );
            patterns.put( "mouse", Pattern.compile( "\\[134\\]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE ) );
            patterns.put( "snake", Pattern.compile( "\\[105\\] \\[455\\]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE ) );
        }

        String apply( String input ) {
            /* Apply your rules here. Change this logic based on the outcome you need. */
            for( Entry<String, Pattern> e : patterns.entrySet() ) {
                Pattern p = e.getValue();
                input = p.matcher( input ).replaceAll( e.getKey() ); //This replaces the original strings in the input
            }

            return input;
        }
    }
}
```